# I'm getting a 'Procedure created with compilation errors.'

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm a beginner to sql and i'm getting a compilation error, can anyone pls guide me with my mistake in the code.

```sql
set serveroutput on;

create or replace procedure p1(n in varchar) as
  cursor c1 is 
    select e_name, inv_amount
    from employee, investment
    where employee.e_id=investment.e_id
    and inv_amount=50000;
  c  c1 %rowtype;
begin
  open c1;
  dbms_output.put_line('e_name'||"||'inv_amount');
  loop
    fetch c1 into c;
    exit when c1 %notfound;
    if(c.inv_amount=n)then
      dbms_output.put_line(c.e_name||c.inv_amount);
    end if;
  end loop;
  close c1;
end;
/
```

Comment: I'm not sure but you know you could just generate this with a query?

Comment: SQL is the query language. This is PL/SQL, the programming language.

Comment: What developer tool are you using? In SQL\*Plus, type `show errors` to list the compilation errors.

Answer (score 1):

I can see some potential errors in your code. Which must be fixed as -

```
set serveroutput on;

create or replace procedure p1(n in varchar)
AS
cursor c1 is 
    select e_name,inv_amount
      from employee,investment
     where employee.e_id=investment.e_id
       and inv_amount=50000;

c c1%rowtype;    -- No space between cursor and ROWTYPE keyword

begin

  open c1;

  dbms_output.put_line('e_name'||''||'inv_amount');  -- It must be 2 single quotes instead of 1 double quotes

  loop

    fetch c1 into c;
    exit when c1%notfound;      -- Remove space
    if(c.inv_amount=n)then
      dbms_output.put_line(c.e_name||c.inv_amount);
    end if;

  end loop;

  close c1;

end;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify this quite a lot:

1. You only care about rows where `inv_amount = n`, so why not add that as a filter condition in the cursor.
2. The Cursor FOR loop construction avoids the need to declare everything explicitly.

```
create or replace procedure p1
    ( n in number )
as
begin
    for r in (
        select e_name, inv_amount
        from   employee e
               join investment i on i.e_id = e.e_id
        where  inv_amount = n
    )
    loop
        dbms_output.put_line(r.e_name || ': ' || r.inv_amount);
    end loop;
end p1;
```

It's also best to write joins using the `join` keyword.

Note that SQL is the query language and PL/SQL is the programming language, so this a PL/SQL procedure, not SQL.

Regarding "Procedure created with compilation errors", you need to get familiar with how to display and trace compilation errors using your development tool. In [SQL*Plus](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqpug/SQL-Plus-quick-start.html), type

```
show errors
```

and you'll get something like this (using your original version of the procedure):

```
Warning: Procedure created with compilation errors.

SQL> show errors
Errors for PROCEDURE P1:

LINE/COL   ERROR
---------- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
10/34      PLS-00112: end-of-line in quoted identifier
10/35      PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "||'inv_amount');" when expecting one of the following:
           ( - + case mod new null <an identifier>
           <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> <a bind variable>
           continue avg count current max min prior sql stddev sum
           variance execute forall merge standard time timestamp
           interval date
           <a string literal with character set specification>
           <a number> <a single-quoted SQL string> pipe
           <an alternatively-quoted string literal with character set specification>
           <
```

You can use the [`list`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqpug/using-scripts-in-SQL-Plus.html#GUID-0A853493-EC7D-416C-ABAD-D6C7F8624902) command to print individual lines, for example line 10 mentioned in the compilation error:

```
SQL> l 10
 10*   dbms_output.put_line('e_name'||"||'inv_amount');
```

or list a range, e.g. lines 8-11:

```
SQL> l 8 11
  8  begin
  9    open c1;
 10    dbms_output.put_line('e_name'||"||'inv_amount');
 11*   loop
```

If you are not using SQL*Plus, you can always query the `user_errors` dictionary view. However, developer tools like SQL Developer, PL/SQL Developer and Toad highlight compilation errors right in the editor so no special commands are needed.